# Insert non-duplicated rows into one table and duplicated rows into anther table in one SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a table `raw` which has duplicated (by PK) rows and I want to insert non-duplicated rows in to table `dedup` and the duplicated rows into `dup`

```
create table raw  (A int, B char(5), C float, D money)
create table dedup(A int, B char(5), C float, D money primary key (A, B))
create table dup  (A int, B char(5), C float, D money)

insert into raw values
(1, 'a', 2, 3), -- insert into dedup
(2, 'b', 3, 34),-- insert into dedup
(3, 'c', 3, 23),-- insert into dup
(3, 'c', 3, 13) -- insert into dup
```

Is it possible to use only one SQL statement to split the raw data set? (Maybe the `merge` with `output` of SQL Server 2008?). **One of the purpose is to reduce the table scans since the raw tables can be very big.**

---

**Update:**
The only way may be create a partitioned view on `dup` and `dedup` and run the following query.

```
insert into theView (a, b, c, d, isDup)
select r.*, case when d.a dup is null 0 else 1 end isDup
from raw r outer apply (
    select a, b
    from raw
    where a = r.a and b = r.b
    group by a, b
    having count(*) > 1
) d
```

It's a little bit cumbersome to create the partition view.

---

**Update:**
*Instead of trigger* should be the way to go.

Comment: I can see how you can do it as two statements (one for dedup, one for dup), but one statement inserting into two separate tables seems a bit of a stretch

Comment: Why oh why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

An insert statement (via MERGE or a normal insert) can affect one table and one table only. Why can't you do this in two statements in a transaction? How often are you doing this? If it's one-time, do two scans vs. one really matter? If it's multiple times, then you can probably have better indexing in place so that you only worry about a certain row once and reduce the work the optimizer has to do to find new rows that need to be sent to the dup/dedup tables.